# How to prepare a web software solution for on-premise deployment

Tags: installation, deployment

I want to start off by saying that had a hard time finding the right Stack community to fit my question in. In the end I thought Server Fault might be the most appropriate. Let me know if my question should be moved to another community.

We are as small tech startup and we host our application in the cloud as a SaaS using Digital Ocean VPS servers. We use free and/or open source technology as Elastic Search, MariaDB, Redis. We do not depend on any cloud technologies that aren't available on premises (except S3 storage, which we have available alternatives).

A potential client of ours would only be willing to go forward with us if we offer on-premise installation of our software stack. But we've never done on-premise installation before. I have tried to look for information about on-premise installation, and the only content we were able to find is the comparison between on-premise and cloud solutions which we already understand.

We have to give our potential client an estimate of the cost of on-premise installation. But not knowing what tasks it involves, makes it hard to estimate the cost. So here are my questions in bulk (no specific order):

1. What is usually expected from the client for an on-premise installation? They install the software themselves with a guide we provide or we send a specialist to install the software at a hourly fee?
2. What kind of preparation tasks should we expect to do that only relates to on-premise?
3. How is the client server fleet maintained and updated?
4. Who is responsible for server security?
5. How do you price an on-premise installation?
6. Who manage the hardware purchase? We send minimum spec and client buys hardware?

So basically all those question boils down to "How does an on-premise installation offer looks like?"

Comment: All these questions are purely between you and the client, and will depend on your and there expertise. There is no one solution. If they run VMs then likely they can handle hardware and spin these up if the spec is adequate. If they are less technically literate you would provide the hardware and support - just remember to stipulate requirements like Internet/firewall access, power etc, and confirm how many u of space you have etc.

Comment: If the client is not expert with hardware you should suuply it so you know exactly what you are working with - particularly with respect of RAID,ECC memory and disk speed/iops.

Comment: Generally the hardware would be the clients responsibility, with software/security the responsibility of the vendor. This us not a hard rule though. It might help you to think along the lines of how a corporate firewall, alarm system or PABX might be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is usually expected from the client for an on-premise installation? They install the software themselves with a guide we provide or we send a specialist to install the software at a hourly fee?**

=> both options exist, ask customer what he expect. If you're in charge of, no hourly fee, but daily fee (you have to do the job, write some survival guides, and teach a little people. It just can't fit in hours of work, but in days)

**What kind of preparation tasks should we expect to do that only relates to on-premise?**

=> plan a workshop with customer, and understand its constraints, so as to fit in. he may want high availability, specific performance, he may want a disaster recovery ready deployment. Also discuss network, security, backup expectations.

**How is the client server fleet maintained and updated?**

=> on premise required by customer, most often he deals with patching/updates. if not, you have to size how long it will take to do it by yourself (and price/sell it )

**Who is responsible for server security?**

=> on premise required by customer, most often he provides servers and installed operating system, using its own security rules.

**How do you price an on-premise installation?**

=> during the kickstart workshop, list all the tasks (and prerequisites for all tasks), and time needed to do each task. Also write who is in charge. After that, sum all **your** tasks in terms of time, and add an security percentage (+20% or +30%), to deal with tasks badly sized in time, to deal with project management overhead, to answer positively to the discount that the customer will ask for, and also to pay for all the time you spent thinking to the final solution without having sold anything.

**Who manage the hardware purchase? We send minimum spec and client buys hardware?**

=> most often, you explain hard specs (cpu/ram/io profile[read/write ratio/io size]/network) and customer purchase the hardware, and install it.